# How to use github flavored markdown in README.md file by default?

Tags: github, markdown

The way markdown-style line end really annoys me, and I found gfm looks better.
But as I wrote the `.md` file and push it ti Github, it just shows as nomal markdown.
Judging the demo on github, it changes line without two blanks, isn't it?
This made me confusing. Just, how can I make this work?

Comment: some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What do you mean by changing line? Do you mean how it does not just recognizes normal end of line? (that annoys me too)

Standard practice for new line is space, space, enter for a new line.
You could also add br html tag and it will do the same.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: (sorrsy for my Chinse English..) Exactally that was what I wanted to ask. By now I have addede hightlight at line end in Vimrc in case that I forget to add space and space.. But I dont like Vim.. If there's a better choice, it would be easier to write README.md for my repo.